# Only 2 tables showing on my Postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm newbie for Postgres and I couldn't list my all tables on database.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c dbname
You are now connected to database "dbname" as user "postgres".
dbname=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
 public | translations    | table | postgres
(2 rows)
```

But I have more than these tables. My web app (which using this database) working well but why i'm only seeing these 2 tables (also these tables isn't belongs to my database, first time I'm seeing them.)

I've created my DB with these commands :

```
CREATE DATABASE "dbname" WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0;
sudo -u postgres psql dbname < db-dump.psql
```

Comment: **By default, the new database will be created by cloning the standard system database template1. A different template can be specified by writing TEMPLATE name. In particular, by writing TEMPLATE template0, you can create a virgin database containing only the standard objects predefined by your version of PostgreSQL. This is useful if you wish to avoid copying any installation-local objects that might have been added to template1.** -  [source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

Comment: So where I did mistake? @Minato

Comment: It might be possible that the databases are different.. I mean the one your app is using might be on a different server and the one u are using might be on the other

Comment: well these might be the default tables as mentioned in the quoted text.

Comment: or may be your application is on a different database itself

Comment: I have only one server (my local server, which in a vagrant box, i'm connecting with ssh and ports forwarded).

Comment: From your shell, enter the command `psql -l` to get a list of the databases which exist on your system.

Comment: By default "\dt" will list tables from "public" schema. Possibly your original database instance may have some other schema?

Comment: @KamchybekJusupov so how can I list tables from different schemas?

Comment: @Eray you have two options: "set search_path schema_name" or "\dt schema_name.*"